# Stateful sink with Apache Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to the stream processing world and am trying to do the following with Spark Structured Streaming -

1. Read messages from a Kafka topic. Each message is a delimited collection of events E.g. sample message -> Event1#Event2#Event3
2. Split each message into individual events.
3. Submit each event to another application using REST through an HTTP sink.
4. I want the sink to be stateful. Inside the sink function, I want to maintain a buffer (some linear data structure) which will hold the events temporarily (I know this could lead to memory issues) in case the external REST application goes down.

Now, I've tried this with Apache Flink and was successful, but I can't figure out how to do this in Spark. The only way to do this seems to be through a *flatMapGroupsWithState* operation. But, that requires a group by to be done, which I have no reason to do.

My job looks like this -

```
public class KafkaJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws StreamingQueryException {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("KafkaJob1").getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> inputStream = spark.readStream().format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "testtopic").load()
                .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)");

        Dataset<String> eventStream = inputStream.flatMap(new EventSplitter(), Encoders.STRING());

        DataStreamWriter<String> streamWriter = eventStream.writeStream().foreach(new HttpSink());

        StreamingQuery query = streamWriter.start();
        query.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

My flatmap function is this -

```
public class EventSplitter implements FlatMapFunction<Row, String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7835625460262333452L;

    public Iterator<String> call(Row rawEventRow) throws Exception {
        List<String> eventList = Collections.emptyList();
        String rawEvent = rawEventRow.getString(1);
        if (rawEvent != null && !rawEvent.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("EventSplitter received event with length " + rawEvent.length());
            String[] eventArr = rawEvent.split("SOME DELIMITER");
            if (eventArr != null && eventArr.length > 0) {
                eventList = Arrays.asList(eventArr);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("EventSplitter generated " + eventList.size() + " events");
        return eventList.iterator();
    }

}
```